# How to create a "generic type pass" for iOS passbook?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, passbook, passkit

I have a requirement to create a "pass" to look like an organization id card. I thought of using "generic" type for this card.
I am not able create a generic pass with the fields name, number, start date, end date, organization  name, division etc...
I am not getting any tutorial to create a generic pass - for iOS passbook.

I need a sample pass.json for "generic pass" and steps to create a pass.

Can anybody help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Shamelessly plugging my own creation  (in Python):
https://github.com/Joride/passmaker

Comment: I have successfully crated the generic pass. when I transfer it via email to my iphone (iOS 7). once i click on download..it is showing null. I am not able to understand what is the problem.

Comment: In the xcode organizer look at the console output. There will be very specific error-messages as to what is wrong with the pass.

Comment: Invalid data error reading pass pass.com.csc.passtest/123456. The passTypeIdentifier or teamIdentifier provided may not match your certificate, or the certificate trust chain could not be verified. This is the log i can see in console... what might be the problem?

Comment: Check to make sure you are using your own PEM files. Also make sure that in the Python code you set the team identifier to match the one that is in the PEM file. You can find the teamID in iTunesConnect. '2R6KT8L4GS' is a fake value in that code that you have to replace with you teamID.

Comment: thank you.. I have resolved my issue. There was a problem with the team identifier.